# $ sdk current java is showing Not using any version of java

Tags: java, application-development, openjdk, ubuntu-sdk

I have sdkman installed in my linux ubuntu 18.04.

**$ sdk version

SDKMAN 5.11.5+713**

I installed amazon java correto 11 using the below command.

**$ sdk install java 11.0.11.9.1-amzn

java 11.0.11.9.1-amzn is already installed.**

I made this java version as default version using the below command
**$ sdk default java 11.0.11.9.1-amzn

Default java version set to 11.0.11.9.1-amzn**

but when i am trying to see, current default java version it shows **not using any version of java**

**$ sdk current java

Not using any version of java**

also when i do this **$ sudo update-alternatives --config java**
i don't get that amazon correto 11 in lists

**$ sudo update-alternatives --config java**
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIFVr.png)

Comment: I was having the same problem with you right now, tried more versions even.

What solved the problem here was... opening a new bash. I kid you not. Hope it solves for you too. (@alexandre-teles suggested that I put this here also as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with you right now, tried more versions even.

What solved the problem here was... opening a new bash. I kid you not. Hope it solves for you too.

Comment: Please consider posting your answer as a comment as it directly provides a solution to the problem presented by OP. Your suggestion is valid though, as sometimes opening a new shell session can solve that kind of problem by reloading system environment variables.